# Floated elements for a responsive layout (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the elements in the following example to float within any empty space instead of inheriting the position from the highest element.  It's a bit hard to explain but the image should explain what I am trying to do:

WIP Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/qrUsh/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Masonry project:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Tim

Comment: thanks i assumed it was going to have to be a position: absolute; method was hoping for a float method i guess, thanks anyway buddy.

Comment: Well, floats won't do that, but the Masonary project still gives the fluid effect you're looking to get.

Comment: yes however for non-js enabled browsers it wouldn't work, so i will have to implement it with absolute positioning.

Comment: The fall back for non-js browsers still looks reasonable.  It's a good compromise, especially when you consider that the % of non-JS enabled browsers is tiny.  You can also use PHP etc. to generate a very nice page layout based on a fixed width for non-JS browsers (putting in the <noscript> tag)

Comment: I wrote a Lightroom gallery plugin using Masonry (converted to use MooTools).  You can see an example result here: http://photographers-toolbox.com/products/jigasawrus/demo/index.html - note how the HTML code still lays out the blocks in the same fashion, based on a fixed width, when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: thanks buddy I plan to do something Similar, thanks for your recommendation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5548/discussion-between-xavier-and-tarmes)